# Android coroutine context causing issues with exception handling

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, kotlin-coroutines

My app has a searchbar through which the user can search for locations and get weather data based on said location.
I am trying to set up appropriate error handling to ensure the app doesn't crash if something goes wrong but when the user enters something other than a valid city name, the app does crash.
In the activity that is hosting my fragments, I have this code:

```
override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
        search.collapseActionView()
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                viewModel.getSearchedLocationWeather(query)
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val currentDestination =
            findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_home).currentDestination
        if (currentDestination?.id == R.id.nav_home) {
            val action =
                MainScreenFragmentDirections.actionNavHomeToSearchResultFragment()
            findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_home).navigate(
                action
            )
        } else if (currentDestination?.id == R.id.nav_saved) {
            val action =
                SavedLocationFragmentDirections.actionNavSavedToNavSearch()
            findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_home).navigate(
                action
            )
        }
    }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(WEATHER_ERROR, "$e for $query")
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(
                        findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                        getString(R.string.invalid_query_input),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                    val snackbarView = snackbar.view
                    val snackbarText =
                        snackbarView.findViewById<TextView>(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text)
                    snackbarText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, R.color.white))
                    snackbarView.background =
                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@MainActivity, R.drawable.snackbar_background)
                    snackbar.show()
                }
            }
        }
        searchView.clearFocus()

        return true
    }
```

The idea is that when the user submits the search request, a function in the `ViewModel` gets called which then reaches out to the data source/repository to get the data and if an exception gets thrown along the way it gets propagated back to the activity where the catch block executes and shows the snackbar.

The function in the `ViewModel` looks like this:

```
fun getSearchedLocationWeather(query: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        try {
            weatherRepository.getSearchedWeather(query).collect { data ->
                try {
                    val weatherData = convertWeatherDtoToWeatherModel(data.weather)
                    _currentWeather.value = LocationWeatherModel(
                        location = LocationModel(data.location.cityName, data.location.country),
                        weather = weatherData
                    )
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d(WEATHER_ERROR, "$query viewmodel")
                    throw e
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(WEATHER_ERROR, "$query viewmodel")
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

The function calls another function in the repository and catches any exceptions thrown along the way.

The repository function looks like this:

```
override fun getSearchedWeather(cityName: String): Flow<LocationWithWeatherDataDto> = flow{
    try{ 
        remoteWeatherDataSource.getWeather(cityName).collect{
        emit(it)
    }
    }
    catch (e : Exception){
        Log.e(WEATHER_ERROR, "Error fetching weather data for $cityName", e)
        throw e
    }

}.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

Again the same logic applies in terms of error handling, it catches any exceptions thrown and propagates it up the call stack.
This is the function it calls in the remote data source:

```
 override fun getWeather(cityName: String): Flow<LocationWithWeatherDataDto> = flow {
        try {
            getCoordinates(cityName).collect { coordinates ->
                val weatherData: WeatherApiModel
                val preferredUnit = dataStoreRepository.getUnit()
                weatherData = when(preferredUnit){
                    Unit.IMPERIAL -> weatherService.getWeather(
                        coordinates.latitude,
                        coordinates.longitude,
                        "minutely,daily,alerts",
                        "imperial",
                        BuildConfig.OWM_KEY
                    )
                    Unit.METRIC -> weatherService.getWeather(
                        coordinates.latitude,
                        coordinates.longitude,
                        "minutely,daily,alerts",
                        "metric",
                        BuildConfig.OWM_KEY
                    )
                    else -> {
                        weatherService.getWeather(
                            coordinates.latitude,
                            coordinates.longitude,
                            "minutely,daily,alerts",
                            "imperial",
                            BuildConfig.OWM_KEY
                        )
                    }
                }
                val combinedData = LocationWithWeatherDataDto(
                    LocationDto(coordinates.name, coordinates.country),
                    weatherData.toWeatherDto()
                )
                emit(combinedData)
            }

        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            Log.e(WEATHER_ERROR, "$e in DataSource")
            throw WeatherFetchException("HTTP error fetching weather data", e)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(WEATHER_ERROR, "$e in DataSource")
            throw WeatherFetchException("Error fetching weather data for $cityName in data source", e)
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

Now because the OpenWeatherMap API endpoint I am using cant directly get weather based on a city name I first need to get the matching coordinates using the geocoding API like this:

```
  override fun getCoordinates(name: String): Flow<CoordinateApiModel> = flow {
        try {
            val coordinatesList = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                weatherService.getCiyCoordinates(name, 1, BuildConfig.OWM_KEY)
            }
            if (coordinatesList.isNotEmpty()) {
                val firstCoordinate = coordinatesList[0]
                emit(firstCoordinate)
            } else {
                throw EmptyApiResponseException("Coordinates list is empty.")
            }
        }
        catch (e: HttpException) {
            throw WeatherFetchException("HTTP error fetching weather", e)
        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            throw e
        }
    }
```

Now if the user enters something that doesn't match any valid city name or one of its abbreviations, the call to  `weatherService.getCiyCoordinates`  returns an empty array which causes the function to throw an exception which then gets caught in `getWeather` which in turn throws another exception after catching the first one. That second exception, the `WeatherFetchException` then gets caught by `getSearchedWeather` which just rethrows it after catching it.
This leads to the exception being caught in the ViewModel by `getSearchedLocationWeather` which again just logs the exception and rethrows it, leading it to be caught in the activity.

I am really confused by this issue but I think that the exceptions are not being caught by the catch block in the activity because I am throwing and catching the exceptions in different coroutine contexts but I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-update this two function and your are good to go but please aware when using throw and try to catch that in response do proper handling

update as same as below

```
 override fun getCoordinates(name: String): Flow<CoordinateApiModel> = flow {
        try {
            val coordinatesList = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                weatherService.getCiyCoordinates(name, 1, BuildConfig.OWM_KEY)
            }
            /* if (coordinatesList.isNotEmpty()) {
                 val firstCoordinate = coordinatesList[0]
                 emit(firstCoordinate)
             } else {
                 throw EmptyApiResponseException("Coordinates list is empty.")
             }*/
            coordinatesList.firstOrNull()?.let { emit(it) } // Emit null if empty
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            throw WeatherFetchException("HTTP error fetching weather", e)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw e
        }
    }
```

you can put toast or any user interface to display msg to user instead of log i put

```
 override fun getWeather(cityName: String): Flow<LocationWithWeatherDataDto> = flow {
        getCoordinates(cityName)
            .collect {
                if (it != null) {
                    try {
                        val weatherData: WeatherApiModel
                        val preferredUnit = dataStoreRepository.getUnit()
                        weatherData = when (preferredUnit) {
                            Unit.IMPERIAL -> weatherService.getWeather(
                                it.latitude,
                                it.longitude,
                                "minutely,daily,alerts",
                                "imperial",
                                BuildConfig.OWM_KEY
                            )

                            Unit.METRIC -> weatherService.getWeather(
                                it.latitude,
                                it.longitude,
                                "minutely,daily,alerts",
                                "metric",
                                BuildConfig.OWM_KEY
                            )

                            else -> {
                                weatherService.getWeather(
                                    it.latitude,
                                    it.longitude,
                                    "minutely,daily,alerts",
                                    "imperial",
                                    BuildConfig.OWM_KEY
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        val combinedData = LocationWithWeatherDataDto(
                            LocationDto(it.name, it.country),
                            weatherData.toWeatherDto()
                        )
                        emit(combinedData)
                    } catch (e: HttpException) {
                        Log.e(WEATHER_ERROR, "$e in DataSource")
                        throw WeatherFetchException("HTTP error fetching weather data", e)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Log.e(WEATHER_ERROR, "$e in DataSource")
                        throw WeatherFetchException("Error fetching weather data for $cityName", e)
                    }
                } else {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                       Log.e("TAG", "data not found")
                    }
                }
            }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```